# Creating a ScrollView within a TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to pick my brains around this...

In my app I've got a table view that lists a load of recipes. A button is added programmatically into each row of the TableView to show what ingredients the user needs. The idea is that a user would click the logo and it'll take them to another view with all the information there.

I was wondering though if the following was possible within a tableview:
[image: http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/6-09-2014/71vuZn.gif]

If so, how would I go about doing it? I've looked around and can't find much help on the issue.

Comment: Do you need to scroll? Or do you want the cell to expand? If you're okay with expanding, there are some well documented tutorials that you can look into called Accordion Cells that will teach you how to expand the tableview on clicking

Comment: Ah, I thought it would have been a scroll that appeared. I'll have a look into that. Thanks!

Comment: As a personal preference I would push a new detail view controller since you recipe/ingredients would probably occupy a lot of space for an expanded cell, just my two cents.